# Finding the max value of a list of tuples, (applying max to the second value of the tuple)

Tags: list, python-3.x, tuples, max

So I have a list of tuples which I created from zipping two lists like this:

```
zipped =list(zip(neighbors, cv_scores))
```

`max(zipped)` produces
    `(49, 0.63941769316909292)`    where 49 is the max value.

However, I'm interesting in finding the max value among the latter value of the tuple (the .63941).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Python **compares tuples lexicographically** so it orders on the first item and only if these are equivalent, it compares the second and so on.

You can however use the **`key=`** in the `max(..)` function, to *compare* on the second element:

```
max(zipped,key=lambda x:x[1])
```

> **Note 1**: Note that you do **not have to construct a `list(..)` if you are only interested in the maximum value**. You can use
>   `max(zip(neighbors,cv_scores),key=lambda x:x[1])`.
>
> **Note 2**: Finding the `max(..)` runs in *O(n)* (linear time) whereas sorting a list runs in *O(n log n)*.

Answer (score 1):

`max(zipped)[1]`
`#returns second element of the tuple`

This should solve your problem in case you want to sort your data 
and find the maximum you can use `itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter
zipped.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
print(zipped[0][1]) #for maximum
```

Comment: Why would you want to sort (even inplace) when calculating the maximum runs in *O(n)* whereas sorting runs in *O(n log n)*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I thought the question was little unclear so I added the sorting